# How can you connect vue with node.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I'm working on a project and I decided to use vue for the front and node for the back.

And also MongoDB for the database.

But I don't know how they should work.

I want to know how to control vue with node.js express.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Vue.js examples](https://vuejs.org/examples/#fetching-data) already?

Comment: You get JSON data from backend via AJAX requests. Same for posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to create the application, you could do a separate frontend/backend. I recommend researching [MVC architecture](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/model-view-controllermvc-architecture-for-node-applications/) for the backend and creating web REST API(which sends/receives serialized json data), which your Vue frontend can call. Would read into  [Vue official documentation](https://vuejs.org/) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_getting_started).

Backend application architecture example:

[image: A general MVC application architecture form]